# 同じフォルダ内にあるモジュールに読み込めるものと読み込めない物がある

Tags: python

同じフォルダに
ex1.py
ex2.py
ex3.py
がおいてあり、

```
import ex1
import ex2
import ex3
```

としているのですが、

import ex1はエラーが出ず読み込まれ、
import ex2とimport ex3はエラー
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ex2`
が出ます。

また、2台のPCで行っていますが片方はエラーが出ず実行され、もう片方はエラーが出るという状況です。
Win10Pro, Python3.7です。
spyderからの実行です。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ファイル名の何処かが全角文字になっているとか、ex1.pyの内容が違っていてsys.pathかカレントフォルダを変えているとか、あるいはex1.pyは同じだが変えた先のフォルダでex2.py,ex3.py有無の差とか。差し支えなければex1.pyのソースを追記した方が良いでしょう。

Comment: ex1.pyの中でos.chdir()していましたが、これが原因でしょうか？
chdirした先にex2.pyとex3.pyを置いたら動きました。
（これをしなくても動いていたPCがあるのがよくわからないのですが…）

Comment: それが原因でしょう。差があるのは、動いている方のPCで元の作業フォルダが(spyderの作業環境設定とかで？)sys.pathかPATHに登録されている可能性が考えられます。os.chdir()の前後でsys.pathと環境変数のPATHをprintして確かめてみてください。それらで判明するようなら情報共有のために自己回答をお願いします。

Comment: 環境変数はprint(os.environ)でよろしいでしょうか？確認しましたが違いはよくわかりませんでした。
また、sys.pathで'C:\\Users\\username'が動かない方のPCには追加されていました。
動くプログラムの方はSpyder上で別のプログラムを実行したあとだった、というのが怪しい気がします。

Comment: これが参考になるでしょう。[Python から環境変数を参照する (os.getenv, os.environ)](https://maku77.github.io/python/env/os-getenv.html) 以前に動かしたプログラムの影響というのは有りそうですね。jupyternotebookとかで良くあるようですし。